Do you guys not give new people hints on improving questions?
So I asked a Recovering old, deleted videos on an iPhone on the main site, which as far as I could tell is on topic. I am new here so I could be wrong, but it was suddenly closed as off topic without any warning and no comments by people to say "Hey, this is off topic because of x and y, you could edit it though".
From what I can see, I have described the problem: There are videos that have been deleted a while back that my brother would like to restore. And I have said what we have found (the website link and other places claiming to be able to do this)
I just want to know is there a way to do this. I'm not asking for illegal software, or anything dodgy. Just can this be done, and if so, how do I go about it? A side note, is are those places linked legit?

Thanks for raising this on Meta. I agree that the question seems to be on-topic as it asks about a practical problem people (your brother in this case) have with the use of Apple products. The close reason picked by the community may not be the best one though, I probably would have picked "opinion-based".
The goal of this site (as of any other SE site) is to find fact-based, verifiable answers to questions. In your scenario, nobody will be able to tell you whether recovery attempts with either the software you mention or by engaging a professional will be successful. This vastly depends on how intensely your brother used the phone since July, how exactly he used it, and probably some additional factors. So all you might get are opinions and stories of success or failure from random people on the internet, neither of which will help you.
I understand that this is unfortunate and doesn't help your brother. But I don't see how people could give a helpful answer here.

Thanks for the clarification. I could update the question with better information. It wasn't really a case of "will this software work", it was more a side note of "is this legitimate" but the main question was  "is this doable to recover the old data even after it has been deleted from the deleted folder, and how can this be done?" Of course, by using legitimate methods

@MCG The problem remains, though, even with the revised version. The only possible answer is "Maybe" (personally, I would say "highly unlikely", given that the deletion happened 3 months ago, but to cite myself, I'm just a random dude on the internet :)).

I accidently edited the meta question rather than the main. I've edited that now too
